# How do I make a logarithmic histogram in SQL?

Tags: sql, histogram, logarithm

My table:

```
val
1
2
3
4
5
6
10
15
```

Desired results:

```
bin | qty 
1   | 1
2   | 2
4   | 3
8   | 3
```

Which means there are, with inclusive/exclusive ranges,

- 1 value between 1-2,
- 2 values between 2-4,
- 3 values between 4-8,
- 3 values between 8-16.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: @GordonLinoff generic :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your bin size, in this case, in logarithmic terms, is 2.

If you wish to use another bin size, substitute the 2s in the script below.

```
select 
    pow(2, floor(ln(val) / ln(2))) as bin,
    count(bin) as qty
from 
    mytable
group by
    bin;
```

### Explanation

First, we take the log of your values in base 2. `log(val, 2)` might work in some RDBMS, but if not, just remember the log property that `log(val, 2) = ln(val) / ln(2)`.

```
val | ln(val) / ln(2)
1   | 0
2   | 1
3   | 1.58496250072
4   | 2
5   | 2.32192809489
```

Then we floor this:

```
val | floor(ln(val) / ln(2))
1   | 0
2   | 1
3   | 1
4   | 2
5   | 2
```

Finally, we use the power of two to transform these floored values into the logarithmic bin values.

```
val | pow(2, floor(ln(val) / ln(2)))
1   | 1
2   | 2
3   | 2
4   | 4
5   | 4
```

The rest is simply grouping by the logarithmic bins and counting.

### Caveats

#### No pow

If your RDBMS does not support `pow(x, y)`, you can use `exp(y * ln(x))`. The expression then becomes:

```
    exp(floor(ln(val) / ln(2)) * ln(2))
```

#### Zero

log(0) is undefined. In the RDBMS I tested, it returns null.

If your table has values of 0, you most likely want to bin them between 0 and 1. To do that, you can wrap the whole expression with ifnull(..., 0), like so:

```
    ifnull(pow(2, floor(ln(val) / ln(2))), 0)
```

#### Negative

The log of negative numbers is undefined... But you probably want to bin them like [0 to -1), [-1 to -2), [-2 to -4), [-4 to -8), etc.

If your database has negative values, you can achieve that binning by first using `abs` in your value, then in the end restoring its original signal by multiplying the result by `val/abs(val)`. Your expression then becomes:

```
pow(2, floor(ln(abs(val)) / ln(2))) * val/abs(val)
```

#### Negative and zero

If your database has both negative and zero values, you should wrap the `ifnull` around everything else. Otherwise, the `val/abs(val)` part would make you divide by zero, re-introducing nulls.

```
ifnull(pow(2, floor(ln(abs(val)) / ln(2))) * val/abs(val), 0)
```

Comment: The floating point arithmetic could have unexpected behavior for certain combinations of values.

Comment: You can supply base within the `log` function instead of division by  `log(2)`

Comment: @Bulat not all RDBMS have that

Comment: @GordonLinoff you mean for non-positive values?

Comment: @GuilhermeBerger . . . log(4) / log(2) might result in 1.9999999997 and your logic would put that in the wrong bucket.

Comment: @GuilhermeBerger Which one does not?

Comment: @Bulat the in-house RDBMS I'm using does not

Comment: @GuilhermeBerger Well some RDBMS systems don't have LOG function.

Comment: @Bulat then I would say those RDBMS are not suited to create logarithmic histograms :) A workaround could be joining with, quite literally, a log table

Comment: ANSI standard is LN() which will still make sense with EXP() function here.

Comment: @Bulat well observed, changed to ln.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85045/discussion-between-bulat-and-guilherme-berger).

Comment: Does this method work fine with values between 0 and 1?